# Spring Boot - Generate JWT on one server and authenticate on another server

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, jwt

I have a distributed system, a user will connect to a server and that server will assign them to a specific node/server to make their API calls.

I want to generate a JWT token on the first server that the client connects to and when the user is redirected to the new server it will authorize them based on their username and password that is pulled from a local database and check the JWT if it is correct (i.e to make sure they're redirected from the first server and no where else).

This might be a bad question but I can't find any resources regarding something like this, how can I generate a JWT token from one server and authenticate it on another server?

Comment: what have you done until know in term of code?

Comment: @rick not much, I researched around and found articles on how to do it on a client/server where the server generates the token and authenticates the user, but nothing like I need, so I didn't know how to implement it.